# Copy lines in .csv based on final value in row

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a .csv file that contains rows of inventory. In order to print tags for the inventory I need to copy each row based on the number of items we have in stock (the final value in each row). Example:

```
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Mini Scarves,400000044187,7.95,6
Football Cap,400000044170,7.95,3
```

I want to know if I can develop a batch script that will read a file (tags.csv) and update it so that it copies each row the appropriate number of times. Example based on input above:

```
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Spiritual Key Ring,400000044194,7.95,12
Mini Scarves,400000044187,7.95,6
Mini Scarves,400000044187,7.95,6
Mini Scarves,400000044187,7.95,6
Mini Scarves,400000044187,7.95,6
Mini Scarves,400000044187,7.95,6
Mini Scarves,400000044187,7.95,6
Football Cap,400000044170,7.95,3
Football Cap,400000044170,7.95,3
Football Cap,400000044170,7.95,3
```

I've been copy and pasting in notepad for quite a while now, but I'd love to click a button instead. Thanks so much for your help in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use batch file but not Excel or VBScript? Also, try to write something by yourself and show it here.

Comment: If you're going to insist on doing this in batch instead of Excel, VBScript, PowerShell, etc., then you'll want to look up how to use the `FOR` command; specifically, `FOR /F`.  There's a fair bit of learning curve.  Other useful commands are `SET /A` and possibly `CALL`, specifically `CALL :{label}`.

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes"

Comment: My apologies for not coming into this with some code to analyze. I guess Excel would be the best tool to do what I need done. I have no experience programming in Excel (macros I assume) and thought this was a pretty trivial task that a smart person would be able to look at and rattle off pretty quickly.

Comment: It is literally as easy as using two nested FOR commands. A FOR /F to read the file and a FOR /L to help write the line multiple times.

Comment: You have been on SO long enough to know that it is not a code writing service.  The site was designed to help programmers with their existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple nested FOR commands based on the input example you provided.

```
@echo off

FOR /F "TOKENS=1-4 DELIMS=," %%G IN (tags.csv) DO (
    FOR /L %%L IN (1,1,%%J) DO echo %%G,%%H,%%I,%%J
)
pause
```